# python | When using the pymysql library to implement the SQL database, there was a syntax error in the SQL statement that could not be resolved

Tags: python, mariadb

> the complete code:
>       import pymysql
>       db=pymysql.Connect(host="localhost",user="root",port=3306,db="spider")
>       cursor=db.cursor()
>       data={
>           'id':'20120001',
>           'name':'BOb',
>           'age':21
>       }
>       table='students'
>       keys=','.join(data.keys())
>       values =','.join(['%s'] * len(data))

```
**sql = "INSERT INTO {table}({keys}) VALUES({values}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".format(table=table,keys=keys,values=values)**
update= ','.join(['{key}=%s'.format(key=key) for key in data])
sql += update
try:
    if cursor.execute(sql,tuple(data.values())*2):
        print("Succesful")
        db.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
    db.rollback()
db.close()
```

> the erro statement:
>       1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATEid='20120001',name='BOb',age=21' at line 1") 
>       I don't know about the way to solve it.if you can help me,thank you very much for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATEid='20120001',name ...
```

`UPDATE` is a keyword.  `id` is a column name.  `UPDATEid` is what?